# Python Pandas, deleting NaN

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I am stuck on a very simple thing. For some reason when I execute this code:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
v = x.dropna(axis=0,how="any")

z = v[["Survived"]]

y = z.where(z == 1)

print (y)
```

It still prints values with NaN, even though I have already done dropna on the whole file and it works. I just want to print rows with value 1. I have tried many variations and I cant seem to fix it. Any ideas?

**Output**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Part of the file I am interested in**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Perhaps access to or a screenshot of `titanic.csv`?

Comment: Or a sample of it

Comment: `df = df[pd.notnull(df['Survived'])]` maybe?

Comment: df=x.dropna(subset=['Survived']) may be this works..

Comment: Nope, still just prints whole document with NaNs and doesnt limit itself to  just Survived

Comment: @Peter, if the answer posted below helped solve your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
y = z.where(z == 1).dropna(subset=['Survived'])
```

Answer (score 1):

SAMPLE DATA:

> ```
>  PassengerId  Survived  pClass
>
>  1            1         3
>
>  2            1         4
>
>  3            0         2
>
>  4            1         9
>
>  5            0         6
>
>  6            0         0
> ```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['PassengerId','Survived', 'pClass']
PassengerIdList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
SurvivedList = [1,1,0,1,0,0]
pClassList = [3,4,2,9,6,0]

newList = list(zip(PassengerIdList,SurvivedList,pClassList))
data = np.array(newList)
# print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
filtered_df = df.loc[df['Survived'] == 1]
print(filtered_df)
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
>   PassengerId    Survived       pClass
>
>      1             1            3
>
>      2             1            4
>
>      4             1            9
> ```

[pyFiddle](https://repl.it/repls/FastEuphoricCertification)

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing you have empty rows in your datasets, try using the:

```
x.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)
```

that should solve the problem or better still, post what your output looks like and we can know what to do.

Comment: Okay, I added my output

Comment: I guess you can still use dropna but the important thing is to make inplace = True

Comment: I saw your output, just try and use inplace = True, am not sure it works for dropna but am very sure x.fillna(-99999, inplace=True) will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also

```
y = z.loc[z['Survived'] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use loc, and just locate every row which fulfills your criteria.

```
survivors = df.loc[df['Survived'] == 1]
```